# Behavioral module for Adder that adds two 64-bit inputs and carry in Input. How to assign carry-out to MSB of the sum?

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

My desired functionality will be to add A, B, and cin (where A and B are 64 bits, and cin is one bit). So the actual sum (the actual result) can either be 64 bits or even 65 bits, right? So I want the output "sum" to be 64 bits, and then the carryout output "cout" would hold the most significant bit of the result. Tried doing this by an `assign` statement, but I guess that's not how you do it as it gives an error. Any other way?

```
module addsub(A, B, cin, sum, cout);
input [63:0] A, B;
input cin;
output reg [63:0] sum; 
output cout;


reg [64:0] actualsum; // the actual result of the addition, which I want to then "split" into cout & sum

always @(A or B or cin) begin
actualsum = A + B + cin;
sum <= actualsum[63:0];
cout <= actualsum[64];
end


endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compile error I got was due to a procedural assignment to `cout` (inside an `always` block).  To fix that, you would declare `cout` as a `reg`.

Good coding practices recommend that you use blocking assignments (`=`) instead of nonblocking assignments (`<=`) for combinational logic.

A much simpler and more conventional way to code this is:

```
module addsub (
    input [63:0] A, B,
    input cin,
    output [63:0] sum, 
    output cout
);

assign {cout, sum} = A + B + cin;

endmodule
```